# Many warnings while deploy glassfish v3

Tags: glassfish

Hello when i am try deploy ear app in glassfish i have got many warning like that :

```
[#|2013-01-14T14:12:52.404+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/pi/applications/person-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-rnull/APP-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/pi/applications/person-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-rnull/APP-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:89)


[#|2013-01-14T14:12:52.407+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/pi/applications/person-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-rnull/APP-INF/lib/resolver-20050927.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/pi/applications/person-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-rnull/APP-INF/lib/resolver-20050927.jar (Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152
```

And other .... Its seems for me that glassfish dont use his own classloader but i am not sure....

Comment: What does _(Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu)_ mean?

Comment: Its means There is no file or directory

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that misconfiguration in your pom.xml is causing this issue. The maven-war-plugin is likely to contain directives customising the class path for your MANIFEST.MF. In my case, I had:

```
 <manifest>
     <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
 </manifest>
```

You should be able to solve it by simply commenting out/removing the directive.

Comment: This helped. Thanks